# Get affected row after INSERT statement Web-Sql

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I am new to `web-sql`. I want to retrieve inserted row after `INSERT` Statement

```
var db = openDatabase('fileuploader', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (username unique, time)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO user (username, time) 
         VALUES (?, ?)',
         [user.name , user.time],
         function(tx, results){
             console.log(results);
        });
});
```

How can I get the last inserted row

Answer (score 0):

If you create tables like this web-sql will create a column named rowid.
This is the primary key for this table.
You could do the following:

```
var db = openDatabase('fileuploader', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (username unique, time)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO user (username, time) 
         VALUES (?, ?)',
         [user.name , user.time],
         function(tx){
             tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user WHERE rowid = (SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM user)',
                function(tx, results){
                  console.log(results);
                });
        });
});
```